# Inequality relating the probabilities of a quantum state to the euclidean distance of states.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

My professor has provided us with the following proposition (without proof).

[image]

I am trying to prove this. i'm having quite some trouble proving the first inequality, right under the first sentence. Ive tried using the triangle inequality, Cauchy-Schwartz and brute forcing several times but to no avail.

I would appreciate any recommendations on how to attempt solving this, while still not providing the entire proof.

Note: We use "states" equivalently with "unit vector". To clarify, we are in a finite dimensional Hilbert space (as per Adrian Keister's comment).

Comment: I assume you're in a finite-dimensional space $H?$ Otherwise Inequality 3.1 wouldn't mean a whole lot.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @KeithMcClary I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to say or how to use it. Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: Disregard. I see they are unit vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\psi^\perp$, $\phi^\perp$ be the projections of $\psi$, $\phi$ on the subspace perpendicular to $x$.

$ |\langle x|\psi\rangle |^2 = 1- \lVert \psi^\perp \rVert ^2 $ and $ |\langle x|\phi\rangle|^2 = 1- \lVert \phi^\perp \rVert ^2 $
so the LHS is
$$ \lvert \lVert \psi^\perp \rVert ^2 - \lVert \phi^\perp \rVert ^2 \rvert = \lvert \lVert \psi^\perp \rVert + \lVert \phi^\perp \rVert  \rvert  \quad \lvert \lVert \psi^\perp \rVert - \lVert \phi^\perp \rVert \rvert \le 2\lvert \lVert \psi^\perp \rVert - \lVert \phi^\perp \rVert \rvert$$
For given lengths, $\lVert \psi^\perp - \phi^\perp \rVert$ is smallest when the vectors are in the same direction, when it equals $\lvert \lVert \psi^\perp \rVert - \lVert \phi^\perp \rVert \rvert$, and
$\lVert \psi^\perp - \phi^\perp \rVert \le \lVert \psi - \phi \rVert$

Comment: Thank you! What prompted you to use projections? Is there something that I'm missing that should have led me to using the projections of $\psi$ and $\phi$?

Comment: I couldn't do anything with the projections on $x$ so I tried to visualise 
 what it looked like in 3D, which led to $\lVert \psi^\perp - \phi^\perp \rVert \le \lVert \psi - \phi \rVert$.